# save command in matlab parfor loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to save a matrix within a parfor loop. I know matlab doesn't allow this and one needs to create a separate program. A bit of googling suggest creating a separate function, say parfor as follows:

```
  function parsave(fname, x,y)

    save(fname, 'x', 'y')

   end
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the program seems to be halting without any error before going through all of the iterations (i.e., it is saving about half of the files). I've got quite a lot of small files (around 1M). Could this be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Calling save directly within parfor violates transparency requirements. Instead you need to pass your variables to another function within which you can call save.

An example [Matlab provides](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-D8103H/index.html?product=DM&solution=1-D8103H) is the following.

Save the following as "parsave.m":

```
    function parsave(fname, x,y)
    save(fname, 'x', 'y')
    end
```

Then run it with:

```
    parfor ii = 1:4
    x = rand(10,10);
    y = ones(1,3);
    parsave(sprintf('output%d.mat', ii), x, y);
    end
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me why this post was downvoted ? I don't see anything in this answer that deserved downvoting according to  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. cc @Stuck_pls_help